# Python - Testing class methods with unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a `Scheduler` class and a test written for `__generate_potential_weeks` using [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

#### main.py

```py
class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self, num_teams, num_weeks):
        self.potential_weeks = self.__generate_potential_weeks(num_teams)
        # Other stuff

    def __generate_potential_weeks(self, num_teams):
        # Does some things
```

#### test_scheduler.py

```py
import unittest
from main import Scheduler

class SchedulerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_generate_weeks(self):
        sch = Scheduler(4, 14)
        weeks = sch.__generate_potential_weeks(4)
```

When I try to test `__generate_potential_weeks`, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Scheduler' object has no attribute '_SchedulerTestCase__generate_potential_weeks'
```

#### Questions

- Why can't the test find `__generate_potential_weeks`
- How can I test `__generate_potential_weeks`? It has some complex logic I would like to test separately from `Scheduler`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double underscore has a special meaning within python. The name will be mangled to avoid a conflicting name in a subclass.

If that wasn't your intent, I'd encourage you to mark it with a single underscore. If it was, you can still access the function by using the mangled name. I think this will work for you: `sch._Scheduler__generate_potential_weeks(4)`

Comment: That solved it. I will accept the answer once SO lets me in a couple minutes